# How do I install quick.db?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I tried installing quick.db in my discord.js bot Example: "npm i quick.db",
I've tried installing it but instead all I get is this error: https://hastebin.com/puwisugivu.sql
How do I fix this?

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me that you need to install Python...

Comment: I've downloaded Python but it still doesn't work, all I get is that error again.

Comment: Downloading is not enough. You also need to install it and then, as the errors also say, ensure it's available via the `PYTHON` or `PATH` environment variables. The other programs need to be able to find it.

Comment: I added python to path, but then node.js isn't working anymore.

Comment: Then you'll need to provide a better explanation than "isn't working", because no one can do anything with that

Answer (score 0):

try installing python bro

https://www.python.org/downloads/

MAKE SURE YOU ADD IT TO PATH!!!11!!